# Generate XML document with namespace in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I want to create an XML document (with namesapace) as per structured below, using PHP. My objective is to create xml which will be pushed to server (using curl).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<InsertData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <userName>string</userName>
  <password>string</password>
  <costCenterCode>string</costCenterCode>
  <consigneeName>string</consigneeName>
  <consigneeAddress>string</consigneeAddress>
  <consigneeMobNo>string</consigneeMobNo>
  <consigneeEmail>string</consigneeEmail>
  <originCityName>string</originCityName>
  <destinationCityName>string</destinationCityName>
  <pieces>string</pieces>
  <weight>string</weight>
  <codAmount>decimal</codAmount>
  <custRefNo>string</custRefNo>
  <productDetails>string</productDetails>
  <fragile>string</fragile>
  <services>string</services>
  <remarks>string</remarks>
  <insuranceValue>string</insuranceValue>
</InsertData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my code to create xml, but issue is that it does not add namespace with child and Web service server is giving me error as it is not structured as per their xml reference.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version = "1.0" ?><Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />');

$body = $xml->addChild("Body");
$tcsAPI = $body->addChild('InsertData');

$tcsAPI->addChild('userName', "xxxxxx");

$tcsAPI->addChild('password', "xxxxxx");

$tcsAPI->addChild('costCenterCode', "CC001");
$tcsAPI->addChild('consigneeName', "MagDev");
$tcsAPI->addChild('consigneeAddress', "Address");
$tcsAPI->addChild('consigneeMobNo', "00000000");
$tcsAPI->addChild('consigneeEmail', "email@some.com");
$tcsAPI->addChild('originCityName', "ORG");
$tcsAPI->addChild('destinationCityName', "DEST");
$tcsAPI->addChild('pieces', "1");
$tcsAPI->addChild('weight', "1");
$tcsAPI->addChild('codAmount', "0");
$tcsAPI->addChild('custRefNo', "WEBT");
$tcsAPI->addChild('productDetails', "Test Product");
$tcsAPI->addChild('fragile', "0");
$tcsAPI->addChild('services', "0");
$tcsAPI->addChild('remarks', "Testing API services");
$tcsAPI->addChild('insuranceValue', "0");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods have an additional argument that allows you to specify the namespace. This will add the namespace definitions (the xmlns attributes) as needed.

```
$xmlns = [
  'soap' => 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope',     
  't' => 'http://tempuri.org/'
];

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<?xml version = "1.0" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />'
);

$body = $xml->addChild("soap:Body", null, $xmlns['soap']);
$tcsAPI = $body->addChild('InsertData', null, $xmlns['t']);

//...

echo $xml->asXml();
```

You can add the namespace definitions manually like attributes. But this is only needed to avoid multiple definitions on descendants. If an ancestor  already defines the namespace the descendant doesn't need to do this any more.

Be aware that attributes are only in a namespace if they have an prefix, default namespaces are only valid for elements. Attributes without a prefix are always in the 'empty' namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tcsAPI->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://tempuri.org/');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much better to add some explanations of what this code is doing as this is helping much more in solving the issue than just the code.